# class CopyTask / Error signature is not compatible with original method

Tags: acumatica

I use the acumatica function to override CopyTask.

```
public delegate PMTask CopyTaskDelegate(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings);
[PXOverride]
  
public PMTask CopyTask(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings, CopyTaskDelegate baseMethod)
{
  return baseMethod(task,ProjectID,settings);
}
```

When I add generate, I have this error.
PX.Objects.PM.PMTask CopyTask(PX.Objects.PM.PMTask, Int32, PX.Objects.PM.DefaultFromTemplateSettings, CopyTaskDelegate) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], **but its signature is not compatible with original method**

Comment: What page number is this on?

Comment: Sorry, the screen is PM.30.10.00. thanks.

Comment: What build of Acumatica is this? Also can you show your graph extension decleration? I copy and pasted your code but do not recieve the error specified when loading the page or utilizing the "Copy Project" action. Is a particular work-flow required to replicate?

Comment: You can find the personalization project. grosfi.ch/MMxsZXb5sqR

Comment: You are declaring your own DefaultFromTemplateSettings class instead of utilzing the one already within the framework, thus why you're gettng the error. If you update your question with the full code I will give a working response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are utilizing the proper references when defining the overrides arguments.

Working example code here:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using System;
using static PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class ProjectEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
    {
        public delegate PMTask CopyTaskDelegate(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings);

        [PXOverride]
        public PMTask CopyTask(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings, CopyTaskDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            return baseMethod(task, ProjectID, settings);
        }
    }
}
```